# Curl command in cron not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, cron

I'm using curl in a cronjob :

```
*/3 * * * * curl -XPUT "elasticsearch3:9200/_snapshot/edump/snapshot-$(date +%Y_%m_%d)?pretty" -H 'Content-Type:application/json'-d'{"ignore_unavailable":true,"include_global_state":false}' > /home/log
```

Which perfectly worked manually. However, in my cronjob (that also have simpler cronjob to make sure the problem isn't just that my cron isn't working (ex : `*/1 * * * * curl http://google.fr > /home/google_log`which is also working) it doesn't work.

I don't even have the '/home/log' to help me and I really don't know what to do ?

Comment: Have you tried to put the curl command inside a shell script file and configure your cronjob to simply call that script file?

Comment: You Sir are a genius or i'm totaly stupid ! one of the two :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found :)
1 : put the command in a script and use cron to execute the script : Working
2 : cron interpret "%" in his way so you have to escape it. (http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/)

Answer (score 4):

I would put the curl command inside a script file

`snapshot.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -XPUT "elasticsearch3:9200/_snapshot/edump/snapshot-$(date +%Y_%m_%d)?pretty" -H 'Content-Type:application/json'-d'{"ignore_unavailable":true,"include_global_state":false}'
```

Make sure to make that file executable (`chmod u+x snapshot.sh`) and then simply modify your cronjob like this:

```
*/3 * * * * /path/to/snapshot.sh > /home/log
```

Comment: It will probably work, tell you in a minute but I'm still looking for understanding the problem putting it into cron

Comment: It worked but as I said I was still looking to understand and that's why I ut my answer below :D thanks anywya for your proposal !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible curl used by cron might be different from what's used in the terminal/shell. Check `which curl` in the terminal (where it's working), and then in either cron or the shell script rather than just `curl https://www.example.com/` use that full path: `/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/curl https://www.example.com/`.